# Is possible to use Instagram tags/xxx/media/recent endpoint in sandbox?

Tags: http, web, request, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to use this endpoint on Instagram API in sandbox:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/<NAME>/media/recent?access_token=<TOKEN>
```

But it returns:

```
{"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
```

So I tried:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/brasilbest/media/recent?access_token=3942609881.87c85c5.9823c28375544c5395f83db9c01a12f8&min_tag_id=0&max_tag_id=10
```

And it returns:

```
{"meta": {"error_type": "APIInvalidParametersError", "code": 400, "error_message": "max_id must not be a media id."}}
```

I tried to use only max_tag_id and only min_tag_id, I also tried different values for max_tag_id and min_tag_id.

My question is how I use max_tag_id and min_tag_id in that request and if it's possible to get recent media while my app is in sandbox ?

For the record, when i use

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=google&access_token=<TOKEN>
```

Or:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/google?access_token=3942609881.87c85c5.9823c28375544c5395f83db9c01a12f8
```

It works. But **v1/tags/google/media/recent** doesn't .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only get 20 posts in Sandbox mode and will only show yours and sandbox users' posts in API response.

If you add a photo with the hashtag, then API response will have just your photo in API response, if not it will be empty.

Once you go live from sandbox, u will get all post.

max_tag_id and min_tag_id will not work in Sandbox mode since it is limited to latest 20 posts.

> The behavior of the API when you are in sandbox mode is the same as
>   when your app is live, but comes with the following restrictions:
>
> - Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user
> - Reduced API rate limits